# Can't access DbContext in class that extends Hub

Tags: c#, dbcontext, aspnetboilerplate, unit-of-work, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to access my DbContext inside my SignalR Hub, but it keeps throwing this exception:

> {"Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'unitOfWork')"}

I don't know what is the problem. Here is my code:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IRepository<MyTable, long> _repository;

    public MyHub (IRepository<MyTable, long> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task Get(TestDto testDto)
    {
        try
        {
            var myData = await _repository.GetDbContext().Set<MyTable>()
                .Include(x => x.obj1)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.list1)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.obj2)
                .ToListAsync();

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("Get", myData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new UserFriendlyException(ex.InnerException.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I'm using ASP.NET Boilerplate framework (.NET core 3.1 and Angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `[UnitOfWork]` attribute and make it a `virtual` method:

```cs
[UnitOfWork]
public virtual async Task Get(TestDto testDto)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or you can inject `IUnitOfWorkManager` to begin a `UnitOfWork` explicitly:

```cs
public async Task Get(TestDto testDto)
{
    using (var uow = UnitOfWorkManager.Begin())
    {
        try
        {
            var myData = await _repository.GetDbContext().Set<MyTable>()
                .Include(x => x.obj1)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.list1)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.obj2)
                .ToListAsync();

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("Get", myData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new UserFriendlyException(ex.InnerException.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```